# I can't start Visual Studio code on Manjaro

Tags: visual-studio-code, manjaro

I use Manjaro and installed VS Code via the snap store (`sudo snap install --classic code`), but if I want to start it nothing happens. I deinstalled it and installed it again but still the same.

Comment: Have you tried running via terminal? Does it output any error?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few options. Probably the easiest is to install with pacman rather than snap since manjaro is based on arch

```sh
sudo pacman -S code
```

You could also install from the [AUR Repository](https://aur.archlinux.org/):

```sh
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/code-git.git
cd code-git
makepkg -sic
```

If that does not work you can manually [download](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads) an rpm package and install with rpm or build manually from a tar

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it soon!